# How do I get make to figure out the correct dependencies to link in the correct downstream object files?

Tags: build, linker, makefile, g++

I'm going to use a small example for reference. Consider a project with:

```
inner_definitions.o : inner_definitions.cpp inner_definitions.h
    gcc $^ -o $@

inner_class_1.o : inner_class_1.cpp inner_class_1.h inner_definitions.h
    gcc $^ -o $@    

inner_class_2.o : inner_class_2.cpp inner_class_2.h inner_definitions.h
    gcc $^ -o $@

outer_class.o : outer_class.cpp outer_class.h inner_class_1.h inner_class_2.h
    gcc $^ -o $@

executable.o : executable.cpp executable.h outer_class.h
    gcc $^ -o $@

executable : __?1__
    __?2__
```

But filling in the blanks `__?1__` for the linker dependencies and `__?2__` for the linker command isn't easy.

In this small example, one could argue that its easy to see that `__?1__ = inner_definitions.o inner_class_1.o inner_class_2.o outer_class.o executable.o` . However, this is clearly not a scalable solution as it forces each developer to understand all the dependencies of the code they are working with so they can figure out the dependencies *by hand* rather than by using the `make` utility.

Another solution would be to have a different variable for each object file that listed all its downstream dependencies: i.e `__?1__ = executable.o $(executable_dependencies)`. This is not a desired solution because it forces the makefile to be compiled in the specific way so the variables are only used when they are fully defined. Also, for really large applications these variables might exceed the maximum variable length.

Yet another solution is to use archive .a files for linking. In this case, we could construct an `inner_class_1.a` that included both `inner_defintions.o` and `inner_class_1.o`, so it could be linked with any object file that needed `inner_class_1.o` without forcing the developer to reconstruct the dependencies. This approach seems promising, but involves having many duplicate files. Also, it doesn't appear that the `gcc` linker can handle nested archive files.

Is there another approach? What is the best approach? Can the `gcc` linker handle nested archive files?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what's wrong with your first attempt at `__?1__`? Why does it require that each developer be familiar with all the dependencies? What would go wrong with that `__?1__` rule if a developer were unfamiliar with, say, `outer_class.o : inner_class_1.h`? And what's so difficult about the `__?1__` command?

Comment: In the first attempt at `__?1__`, the problem is this: a naive developer, without understanding the system, would see that executable.cpp only has `#include "outer_class.h"` and so would set `__?1__ = executable.o outer_class.o`. This would cause an error because the gnu linker isn't smart enough to link in the other object files needed to build a complete binary.

The `__?2__` is probably easy, given the right `__?1__1`, but I wanted to leave it open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The job you're trying to automate (picking the right object files to satisfy all references) is usually left to the linker, using static libraries (".a" files) to group the candidate object files, just as you suggest.

An important detail you may be missing: If you pass the linker an archive, it will only link in those files from the archive that are actually needed. So you can create archives at a fairly coarse level of granularity without necessarily bloating all your executables -- the linker will pick just what it needs -- although can easily end up with needlessly slow builds if you take this approach too far.

The GNU linker will not pull objects out of nested libraries. If you want to make one big library by merging many small ones, you can do that with the "addlib" command in an [ar script](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/ar-scripts.html). That will give you a single archive containing all of the object files without any nested library structure.

If the duplication of having .o files and .a files containing the same object code lying around bothers you, [the fine manual describes a way to have make update the archives "directly"](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/make/Archives.html#Archives).

Comment: Also, the recursive .a files will also have lots of extra object code lying around (even without any .o files).

Comment: Giving the linker static libraries containing more object files than are really needed is normal (try `ar t /usr/lib/libc.a` for example) and scales reasonably far.  Choosing the right granularity of archives is a matter of trade-offs.  For unit tests I would aim to give the linker less than "the complete list", so that unexpected dependencies on other modules result in linker errors rather than silently creeping in.

Comment: "recursive .a files" sounds like you might be heading in a direction "considered harmful" http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/

Comment: Another direction you might like to explore: You could split your application up into *dynamic* (aka "shared") libraries. These can refer to each other, so you need have no code duplication at all.

Comment: @slowdog by "recursive .a files" I meant that I could make `outer_class.a` that contained `outer_class.o`, `inner_class1.a` and `inner_class2.a`. This fails because, as far as I'm aware, the linker doesn't recursively open archive files. The dynamic libraries still doesn't solve the problem of trying to figure out the downstream dependencies. Is there a way to avoid passing all the object files to the linker, either as a list of objects (generated by hand or computed) or in a massive `.a` file?

Comment: As I said, nested archives won't work. Using "ar -M" with a script is the solution to that (edited the answer a little to make that clearer). Someone has to figure out the dependencies. If you pass everything to the linker, then the linker will do it for you. I would recommend you split your project into modules, specify the dependencies among modules manually, and pass all objects for the *modules* you know you need to the linker. Then the linker can worry about the individual object files. It's a compromise between micromanaging the code and building a monolith.

Comment: Dynamic libraries do solve the "downstream dependency" problem: You can build a "libfoo.so", linking it against "libbar.so". If you then build an executable specifying only "libfoo.so", the linker will automatically pull in "libbar.so".

Comment: Ooh, dynamic libraries sound like the way to go. Is there any drawback to have a separate library for each `.o` file with the same dependencies?

Comment: Dynamic libraries are nice. Drawbacks: Deployment becomes annoying when your application consists of dozens of little libraries. Also, you may eventually find startup time becoming a problem, as dynamic libraries effectively defer a part of the linking process until runtime. Some discussion about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410691/why-is-the-startup-of-an-app-on-linux-slower-when-using-shared-libs

Comment: Using dynamic libraries doesn't solve the problem of unnecessary rebuilding.

Comment: @beta: I think make usually handle the unnecessary rebuilding ok, I'm more interested in the linking dependencies.
@slowdog: So dynamic libraries don't actually solve the problem. The problem of "how do I convince `make` to figure out the dependencies and link in the all of the correct object files". They are one way to do it, but probably won't scale with many files ( because of the cost at runtime ) and don't actually solve the problem ( esp since sometimes there is a need to not use dynamic libraries ).

Comment: The answer to "how do I convince make to figure out the dependencies and link in the all of the correct object files" is "you can't, that's not what make does".

Comment: Ah, so thats the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Your makefile must have a list of objects to link together, like so:

```
OBJ_FILES = inner_definitions.o inner_class_1.o inner_class_2.o \ 
outer_class.o executable.o

executable : $(OBJ_FILES)
    gcc $^ -o $@
```

Someone must write this; gcc can't do it for you, Make can't do it for you. Not every developer on the project needs to know how to construct that list, only the one who writes that part of the makefile. All the others will use that makefile, and a developer who adds a new dependency (e.g. `inner_class_3`) can add it to the list.

And if your makefile is lost in a fire and the only developer who knows all the dependencies is hit by a bus, it really isn't hard to reconstruct the list: when you try to make `executable`, the linker complains that `foo::bar()` is undefined, you grep around and discover that `foo::bar()` is defined in `inner_class_2.cpp`, you add `inner_class_2.o` to the list. Repeat until the linker stops complaining.

**P.S.** Once that's in order, you can simplify the rest of the makefile quite a lot:

```
%.o: %.cpp %.h
    gcc -c $< -o $@

inner_class_1.o inner_class_2.o : inner_definitions.h

outer_class.o : inner_class_1.h inner_class_2.h

executable.o : outer_class.h
```

**EDIT:**

1. The method I suggested does *not* require listing every object file that can be made, just the ones that are actually needed to build `executable`; I inferred the list from your question.

   Passing extra object files to the linker makes no difference to the final executable, but it does lead to unnecessary rebuilding. For example, suppose you add `alien.o` to `OBJ_FILES`. Then if you modify `alien.cpp` and run `make executable`, it will rebuild `alien.o` and `executable` even though there's no real need to do so. **Correction (thanks to slowdog):** unnecessary object files go into the final executable as dead code-- but I'm still right about unnecessary rebuilding.

   Organizing object files into archives and shared libraries is often convenient, but doesn't really change anything here.

   I know of no robust way to automatically construct the object list -- that is, a way that could deal with problem cases such as when the same function is defined in two different source files. This could become a real problem if unit tests are involved. **But** you could do it within your makefile **if** you follow a simple naming convention.

   The trick for doing it within your makefile is a pretty advanced one. I honestly think you'd be better off doing this the simple way until you're more comfortable with the tools.

**EDIT:**
All right, here's an outline of the advanced technique.

First, consider all of the #included header files. It would be nice to have Make handle the dependencies instead of putting them in by hand, as in the makefile above. And this is a straightforward task: if X.cpp #includes Y.h (either directly or through some chain of #included header files), then X.o will depend on Y.h. This has already been worked out as ["Advanced Auto-Dependency Generation"](http://mad-scientist.net/make/autodep.html). But if you follow a strict naming convention, you can take it a step further: if everything declared but not defines in X.h is defined in X.cpp, then by following the same tree of #include statements we should be able to construct a list of the needed object files, which will then be the dependencies of `executable`.

This really is a lot to absorb at once, so I won't try to work through an example. I suggest you look over the document and see how it can generate the Y.h dependencies, then try applying it to the example makefile, then think about what the "step further" should do.

Later you can apply it to the test harness, where the object files are, e.g., `outer_class.o`, `stub_inner_class_1.o`, `stub_inner_class_2.o` and `test_outer_class.o`.

Comment: So that step of "and grep around and discover that `foo::bar()` is defined in ..." is the step I want to make easy. The thought is that the developer who creates a new file would know what its immediate dependencies are, and would add those - make would figure out all the downstream dependencies and link them in as well. 

For reference, I'm actualy doing:  http://www.xs4all.nl/~evbergen/nonrecursive-make.html

Comment: Also, this involves passing *every* object file to the linker. Is this a scalable solution for large projects?

Comment: "Passing extra object files to the linker makes no difference to the final executable" -- That's not true. All code from individual object files passed to the GNU linker goes into the executable. Unnecessary object files are only ignored if they're inside a static library.

Comment: I believe that we're now on the same page about what the problem is. And your answer is that "[you] know of no robust way to automatically construct the object list" except by "following a simple naming convention". How would that work? I'm willing to try an advanced trick - I'm asking the question specifically to learn the trick.